# Order By in esql

Tags: messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I have an xml message like this

```
<Body>
   <test>
       <element>2</element>
       <element>6</element>
       <element>1</element>
   </test>
</Body>
```

and i want to select the element with the lowest number

something like this

```
SET data[] = SELECT e FROM Output.Body.test.element[] AS e ORDER BY e.element;
```

I would have done this if the "ORDER BY" is supported in esql select but it is not, So is there any other way to do something like this?

I know the sql statements can be supported if i used PASSTHRU statement which passes the statement to the DBMS directly, but i am not using DBMS here, i am selecting from xml message.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to do the sorting yourself, either implement it in ESQL, or use some Java library.

Comment: Given the lack of ORDER BY support, you'll need to iterate through the list and select the element with the lowest number, as Attila wrote.

Answer (score 2):

With the following link you can write a Quick Sort procedure to order your list. Then, you just have take the first element of the list.

Source: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=273722#27372

*(I only posted a link because the procedure code is pretty huge and could be updated by his creator)*